# MATLAB 2013 installation on a 32-bit Linux (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: java, linux, matlab

I'm trying to install the 64-bit MATLAB 2013a on to a 32-bit Linux, something which I have been able to do in the past (who knows how) and is entirely possible according to Mathworks forum assistants. Note this is a fresh installation of Xubuntu.

I'm installing from an ISO, but I mount the image and copy the contents into my home folder. I've tried a few variations of running the install script, firstly:
./install - this just shows an error saying that it can't locate the java directory.
./install -glnxa64 - this gives a syntax error:

/tmp/mathworks_17016/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: 1:    /tmp/mathworks_17016/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

./install -glnxa64 -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre - This starts the installer (seemingly) by opening a Matlab window, but then prints a massive wall of text; something like 'exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException'

Any ideas / comments will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving your feedback I am pretty sure that it is impossible to install 64bit Matlab on pure 32bit Linux without any tweaks. If everything has to work right you should at least install 64bit Linux kernel and libs for MATLAB compiler, this may be your chance. Follow [this guide](http://neuro.debian.net/blog/2013/2013-05-31_matlab_64bit_on_32bit.html) and hopefully everything will work right. Just be aware, that playing with Linux kernel should be done with great care and if you do something wrong you may end up without working system.

Comment: Thanks for all the help though. I've just finished installing a 64-bit version of Xubuntu, will try and install MATLAB again soon. Cheers!

Comment: @user2742907 Good luck, post any info of how is it going.